# Reading S3 files from two different buckets but adding it to one list variable

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services

I have a below code which reads all the `S3` files from a particular `S3` bucket and then it adds all those files in a `objectList` variable.

```
private static async Task<List<String>> ListObjects()
{
    var objectList = new List<String>();

    var firstRequest = new ListObjectsV2Request()
    {
        BucketName = _firstS3BucketName,
        MaxKeys = _configurationStateManager.GetState().MaxReferenceDataKeys
    };

    ListObjectsV2Response getListObjectResponse;

    do
    {
        getListObjectResponse = await GetListObjectResponse(firstRequest);
        if (getListObjectResponse != null && getListObjectResponse.S3Objects != null && getListObjectResponse.S3Objects.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var s3Object in getListObjectResponse.S3Objects)
            {
                // here s3Object.Key has the file name as it's prefix
                objectList.Add(s3Object.Key);
            }
        }

        firstRequest.ContinuationToken = getListObjectResponse.NextContinuationToken;
    }
    while (getListObjectResponse.IsTruncated);

    if (getListObjectResponse == null || getListObjectResponse.S3Objects == null ||
        getListObjectResponse.S3Objects.Count == 0)
    {
        return null;
    }

    return objectList;
}

private static Task<ListObjectsV2Response> GetListObjectResponse(ListObjectsV2Request _request)
{
    return _adapter.ReferenceDataAdapter.ListObjectsV2Async(_request);
}
```

`s3Object.Key` has the file name in it. Format for the file name is like this - `SomeFileName~MM-DD-YYYY.txt`

**Problem Statement**

I am trying to modify the above code in such a way so that it can read some files from one S3 bucket and few other files from second S3 bucket but add all those files in the same `objectList` variable. Here is what I need to do:

- I don't want to read `CustomerOutput~MM-DD-YYYY.txt` and `AccountManager~MM-DD-YYYY.txt` from first S3 bucket but read all other files.
- But I only want to read `CustomerOutput~MM-DD-YYYY.txt` and `AccountManager~MM-DD-YYYY.txt` from second S3 bucket and avoid all other files.

What is the best and generic way to do above problem? I came up with below code which does the job but it isn't the nice way to do it as I am repeating lot of things which can be made generic.

```
private static async Task<List<String>> ListObjects()
{
    var objectList = new List<String>();

    var firstRequest = new ListObjectsV2Request()
    {
        BucketName = _firstS3BucketName,
        MaxKeys = _configurationStateManager.GetState().MaxReferenceDataKeys
    };

    var secondRequest = new ListObjectsV2Request()
    {
        BucketName = _secondS3BucketName,
        MaxKeys = _configurationStateManager.GetState().MaxReferenceDataKeys
    };


    ListObjectsV2Response firstResponse;
    ListObjectsV2Response secondResponse;

    do
    {
        firstResponse = await GetListObjectResponse(firstRequest);
        secondResponse = await GetListObjectResponse(secondRequest);

        if (firstResponse != null && firstResponse.S3Objects != null && firstResponse.S3Objects.Count > 0
        && secondResponse != null && secondResponse.S3Objects != null && secondResponse.S3Objects.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var s3Object in firstResponse.S3Objects)
            {
                var objectDelimiterIndex = s3Object.Key.IndexOf("~");
                if (objectDelimiterIndex < 0) continue;

                // do not read CustomerOutput and AccountManager from first s3 bucket but read all other files
                if (!s3Object.Key.Substring(0, objectDelimiterIndex).Equals(ReferenceFiles.CustomerOutput.ToString(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                || !s3Object.Key.Substring(0, objectDelimiterIndex).Equals(ReferenceFiles.AccountManager.ToString(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    objectList.Add(s3Object.Key);
                }
            }

            foreach (var s3Object in secondResponse.S3Objects)
            {
                var objectDelimiterIndex = s3Object.Key.IndexOf("~");
                if (objectDelimiterIndex < 0) continue;

                // Only read CustomerOutput and AccountManager from second s3 bucket and avoid all other files
                if (s3Object.Key.Substring(0, objectDelimiterIndex).Equals(ReferenceFiles.CustomerOutput.ToString(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                    || s3Object.Key.Substring(0, objectDelimiterIndex).Equals(ReferenceFiles.AccountManager.ToString(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    objectList.Add(s3Object.Key);
                }
            }
        }

        firstRequest.ContinuationToken = firstResponse.NextContinuationToken;
        secondRequest.ContinuationToken = secondResponse.NextContinuationToken;
    }
    while (firstResponse.IsTruncated && secondResponse.IsTruncated);

    if (firstResponse == null || firstResponse.S3Objects == null ||
        firstResponse.S3Objects.Count == 0 || secondResponse == null || secondResponse.S3Objects == null ||
        secondResponse.S3Objects.Count == 0)
    {
        return null;
    }

    return objectList;
}
```

Comment: From a high level perspective, it seems you would want to pass in (1) a predicate filter and (2) a bool to declare whether the filter is to include or exclude items passing the filter.

Comment: Do you think you can provide an example basis on your suggestion on how to use a predicate filter and a bool here in my code to solve this efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my understanding you can separate your code like this:

- Have an orchestrator which knows

  - how to retrieve data from which bucket
  - how to combine the result
- Have a worker which knows

  - how to call paged API
  - how to verify the response
  - how to filter objects based on the parameters

---

#### Orchestrator

```cs
private static async Task<List<string>> ListObjectsFromTwoBucketsAsync()
{
    var firstBucketKeys = await ListObjectKeysAsync(_firstS3BucketName, false);
    var secondBucketKeys = await ListObjectKeysAsync(_secondS3BucketName, true);

    return firstBucketKeys?.Any() && secondBucketKeys?.Any()
            ? firstBucketKeys.Union(secondBucketKeys)
            : null;
}
```

Notes:

- The order of the keys here might be different than in your code
- You can issue the two queries concurrently via `Task.WhenAll` if you need

#### Worker

```
private static async Task<List<string>> ListObjectKeysAsync(string bucketName, bool shouldIncludeSpecificOnly)
{
    var request = new ListObjectsV2Request()
    {
        BucketName = bucketName,
        MaxKeys = _configurationStateManager.GetState().MaxReferenceDataKeys
    };
    const string customerOutput = ReferenceFiles.CustomerOutput.ToString();
    const string accountManager = ReferenceFiles.AccountManager.ToString();

    ListObjectsV2Response response;
    var result = new List<string>();

    do
    {
        response = await GetListObjectResponse(request);

        if (!(response?.S3Objects?.Any() ?? false))
            return null;
            

        var toBeAdded = from s3Object in response.S3Objects
                        let delimiterIndex = s3Object.Key.IndexOf("~")
                        where delimiterIndex >= 0
                        let keyPrefix = s3Object.Key[..delimiterIndex]
                        where customerOutput.Equals(keyPrefix, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && shouldIncludeSpecificOnly
                            || accountManager.Equals(keyPrefix, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && shouldIncludeSpecificOnly
                            || !shouldIncludeSpecificOnly
                        select s3Object.Key;

        result.AddRange(toBeAdded);
               
        request.ContinuationToken = response.NextContinuationToken;
    }
    while (response.IsTruncated);

    return result;
}
```

- Receive the bucket's name as parameter
- "Compute" the `customerOuput` and `accountManager` strings only once
- Issue the request
- Examine the response

  - I've tried to make checking logic more concise
  - I've used [null conditional operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-), [null-coalescing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator), and LINQ's [`Any`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=net-7.0)
- Filter the response's objects

  - I've rewrote it to use LINQ
  - The interesting part is the second `where` which combines all the conditions
- Retrieve the next chunk

---

If any of the code piece is not clear, please let me know and I will add more description.

Answer (score 0):

```
[Flags]
public enum IgnoreFlag
{
SourceOne = 1,
SourceTwo = 2,
Both = 3
}

Dictionary<string, IgnoreFlag> ignoreFiles = new Dictionary<string, IgnoreFlag>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);

//ignore for source1
if (ignoreFiles.ContainsKey(s3Object.Key.Substring(0, objectDelimiterIndex))
&& (ignoreFiles[s3Object.Key.Substring(0, objectDelimiterIndex)] & IgnoreFlag.SourceOne) == IgnoreFlag.SourceOne)
{
    continue;
}
objectList.Add(s3Object.Key);

//ignore for source2
if (ignoreFiles.ContainsKey(s3Object.Key.Substring(0, objectDelimiterIndex))
&& (ignoreFiles[s3Object.Key.Substring(0, objectDelimiterIndex)] & IgnoreFlag.SourceTwo) == IgnoreFlag.SourceTwo)
{
    continue; 
}

objectList.Add(s3Object.Key);
```

Maybe you can send a dictionary of file's to ignore with a flag of source 1 or 2 or both?
By sending dictionary of files you want to ignore as key and flag enum as value, you are given the flexibility of ignoring it from source 1 ,source 2, or both by doing a logical & operator on the flag.

ex. Both = 3 or 0b11
doing & on
SourceOne = 1 or 0b01
will return true
and doing
& on SourceTwo = 2 or 0b10
will also return true

This was simple solution for your existing code.

### Your boolean logic

`firstResponse != null && firstResponse.S3Objects != null && firstResponse.S3Objects.Count > 0`

this check can probably be moved to a method so you can just call
`ValidResponse(firstResponse) && ValidResponse(secondResponse)`

`!(ValidResponse(firstResponse) && ValidResponse(secondResponse))`

to reduce code duplication, reduce chance of typo, and change it in one location if you have to make change.

(you can make a method for my suggested boolean case as well with flag as input if you decide to use it)

Comment: Welcome to the site! Do you have more feedback to give about the OP’s code? Giving an explanation along with a working example of what you mean is wonderful, but answers should review the OP’s code, and not merely rewrite it.

Comment: Yeah I can add some comments